# Delete a button from a table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I have a table, with 7 columns, and last of it contains 2 buttons (Edit and Delete), for each new row. Down of the table, I have an add button, for enter new rows. I want to press the add button, and just the new rows entered to contain that buttons (edit and delete). How can I delete them?

Comment: Sample code can be nice.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to understand your issue, you have to post a a [complete, minimal, reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the last row, use this JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
table.deleteRow(table.rows.length - 1);
```